# What is happning when I use echo and return in my php function?

Tags: php, function, return-value

I make a function and echo a string on it. After that, I going to use this function to concatenation with a string. Why is this function value appearing first before concatenation string?

```
function my_function(){
    echo " Second Text";
}

echo " First Text, ".my_function();
```

*Output:*  `Second Text First Text,`

My expected output was `First Text, Second Text`

Another hand when I use `return` in function alternative of `echo`. I get my expected output

```
function my_function(){
    return " Second Text";
}
echo " First Text, ".my_function();
```

*Output:*  `First Text, Second Text`

Why am I not getting my expected output by `echo` in function?

Comment: I couldn't find the difference between `Output` and `My expected output was`

Comment: Before the `echo` outside the function, PHP attempts to concatenate the text with the return of the function, but the function `echo`s and returns `NULL`, then the `echo` executes.

Comment: Is the output stated in the first case correct?  For the first output you state the output is the same as your expectation and ask why your not getting expected output.

Comment: It was my writing mistake. I make correction

Comment: @TanmoyBiswas Have answered it. I understood.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have used your comment to explain why it happens (as my explanation was off). I have given due credits, hope it's okay?

Comment: Instead of echo in your function, use return. Then the string will be returned and concatenated the way you want it. It's usually a bad idea to echo things in functions. For one thing, it makes it harder to debug. since you need to look around in the code to find what happens where.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson when I use echo why it change my output right to left

Comment: Did you read the comment from @AbraCadaver? He've already explained it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

```
function my_function () {
    echo " Second Text";
}

echo " First Text, " . my_function();
```

What happens internally is something like:

```
echo " First Text, " . echo " Second Text";
```

**Grabbing from [AbraCadaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2844319/abracadaver)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814743/what-is-happning-when-i-use-echo-and-return-in-my-php-function#comment84633311_48814743):**

Before the `echo` outside the function, PHP attempts to concatenate the text with the return of the function, but the function `echo`s and returns `NULL`, then the echo executes. The same thing happens with `var_dump()` as well.

You have two choices:

1. As you mentioned, use `return`.
2. Use a comma for it. See below.

The below code will give you expected output:

```
function my_function () {
    echo " Second Text";
}

echo " First Text, ", my_function();
```

I have checked all the code with [PHP Tester](http://phptester.net/) and it works as expected.

Comment: Your explanation for the internal stuff is off. It doesn't explain why the output is "Second Text First Text," or why PHP evaluates from right to left.

Comment: Yes, This code is working well in PHP Tester my expected output is there. But when I run this code on my localhost. It is same as my previous output. I using PHP  7 and xampp

Comment: @TanmoyBiswas Try clearing cache, and make sure it's saved properly, like you are editing the right file and stuff.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar I clear my browser cache properly. But the result is still same

Answer (score 0):

When doing the initial echo, with concat

```
function my_function(){
    echo " Second Text";
}

echo " First Text, ".my_function();
```

PHP must first process the function, because of concatenation, in other words it needs the return from the function before it can complete the echo command.  So given that it executes `my_function` then finally executes the echo.  This results in the functions contents being echoed first, and then the outside echo second.

Placing a comma with echo acts like putting another argument, except that echo is not a function but a language construct so you can think of it like this (but not do it like this) `echo(" First Text, ",my_function())` in which case echo just outputs each part separately. When you use the `.` it first builds the string (which it cant do without calling the function first) then it outputs the whole construct.

So these should be options to do what you want

```
//Option 1
function my_function(){
    return " Second Text";
}

echo " First Text, ".my_function();

//Option 2
function my_function(){
    echo " Second Text";
}

echo " First Text, ";
my_function();

//Option 3

function my_function(){
    echo " Second Text";
}

echo " First Text, ",my_function();
```

Personally I would go with the first one as it's the most flexible ( and looks the best IMO ).  For example

```
//Option 1
echo " First Text, ".my_function()." Third Text";

//Option 2 
echo " First Text, ";
my_function();
echo " Third Text";

//Option 3
echo " First Text, ",my_function()," Third Text";
```

For me the comma is really an odd choice while it may work, it looks Odd to my eyes when I see it in code, because it has a kind of special use in echo.  I also try to never echo directly from a function, but I generally do only OOP (Object Oriented Programming ) so for me it's largely a matter of scope.

Hope that helps.